# How to get the name of the class from which a method call originates

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, xcode7

I have tried a few things,

1. `id class = [self.navigationController.viewControllers[1] class];`
2. `class *Routeview=(class *)self.parentViewController;`

To be more precise,
 I have a class A which has a method method1, and I have two more classes class B and class C. so I want to find out at runtime which class is calling the method1 Class B or class C.

Answer (score 0):

try following:

Add this in your method,

```
NSString *sourceString = [[NSThread callStackSymbols] objectAtIndex:1];
    // Example: 1   UIKit                               0x00540c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
    NSCharacterSet *separatorSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" -[]+?.,"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[sourceString  componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separatorSet]];
    [array removeObject:@""];

NSLog(@"Stack = %@", [array objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"Framework = %@", [array objectAtIndex:1]);
NSLog(@"Memory address = %@", [array objectAtIndex:2]);
NSLog(@"Class caller = %@", [array objectAtIndex:3]);
NSLog(@"Function caller = %@", [array objectAtIndex:4]);
```

Comment: The above solution did not work for me. I have solved the problem by using  delegate.Thank you very much....